# How to truncate a list based on an arbitrary value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to trim a list of all trailing `a` values, where `a` is some arbitrary value.

Example:

- `[1, 2, 3, a, 5, a, a, a, a]` → `[1, 2, 3, a, 5]`

Another example. Say `a = None`:

- `[1, None, 2, None, 3, None, None, None, 7, None, None, None, None, None, None]` 
  →
  `[1, None, 2, None, 3, None, None, None, 7]`

`filter` removes them but also removes the ones in between. I'd like a way to maintain the order, preserve the elements in between, and only remove the trailing ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution is to use `pop`, which removes the element at the end of the list. This solution is in-place, meaning it changes the contents of the input list.

```py
def remove_trailing(lst, val=None):
    while lst and lst[-1] == val:
        lst.pop()
```

Usage:

```py
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, None, 5, None, None, None, None]
>>> remove_trailing(lst)
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, None, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your list is `[1, 2, 3, -1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1]` where `-1` is the arbitrary value.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, -1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1]
i = len(list) - 1
while i >= 0 and list[i] == -1:
    i = i-1
print(list[:i+1])
```

The code above will remove all the arbitrary values that occur continuously at the end. Hope it helps!

Comment: Agreed. I made the incorrect assumption that the list will contain some elements other than the arbitrary elements to be removed.